# Enviando notificação para o Microsoft Teams pelo Jenkins. [hostname in certificate didn't match]

Tags: jenkins

Tenho um problema ao enviar a notificação do job no trabalho, aqui utilizo a VPN e firewall da empresa. O Job foi executado com sucesso e é possível verificar no log que o conector foi ativado, mas a notificação não é enviada.

Se eu enviar uma mensagem por curl manual ele funciona corretamente

```
 script {
                    final String url = "webhook"

                    final String response = sh(script: "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data '{\"text\":\"Message sent by jenkins\"}' webhook", returnStdout: true).trim()

                    echo response
                }
```

[image]

Mas de forma automatizada pelo Jenkins não está funcionando

Segue a parte do pipeline do Office 365

```
post {
      failure {
        office365ConnectorSend webhookUrl: "$WEB_HOOK_URL",
                factDefinitions: [[name: "message", template: "Falha: Deploy em $DEPLOY_STAGE de $REPO"],
                                  [name: "status", template: "Falha"]],
                color: "#FF0000",
                status: "Failure"

        sh("curl -v --location --request POST '$WEB_HOOK_URL' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{\"@type\": \"MessageCard\",\"@context\": \"http://schema.org/extensions\",\"themeColor\": \"#FF0000\",\"summary\": \"Teste de Mensagens EndPoint Jenkins\",\"sections\": [{\"activityTitle\": \"Jenkins avisa!\",\"activitySubtitle\": \"Resultado do build\",\"activityImage\": \"https://ac-buckets-dev-acpublicmedia-2cxkd4j0deg1.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/RedDownArrow.png\",\"facts\": [{\"name\": \"Message\",\"value\": \"FALHA: Deploy em $DEPLOY_STAGE de $REPO\"}, {\"name\": \"Status\",\"value\": \"Failure\"},{\"name\": \"Job\",\"value\": \"${JOB_NAME}:${BUILD_NUMBER}\"}],\"markdown\": true}],\"potentialAction\": [{\"@type\": \"OpenUri\",\"name\": \"Abrir Build\",\"targets\": [{ \"os\": \"default\", \"uri\": \"${BUILD_URL}\" }]}]}'")
      }
      success {
        office365ConnectorSend webhookUrl: "$WEB_HOOK_URL",
                factDefinitions: [[name: "message", template: "Sucess: Deploy em $DEPLOY_STAGE de $REPO"],
                                  [name: "status", template: "Sucesso"]],
                color: "#00FF00",
                status: "Success"

        sh("curl -v --location --request POST '$WEB_HOOK_URL' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{\"@type\": \"MessageCard\",\"@context\": \"http://schema.org/extensions\",\"themeColor\": \"#00FF00\",\"summary\": \"Teste de Mensagens EndPoint Jenkins\",\"sections\": [{\"activityTitle\": \"Jenkins avisa!\",\"activitySubtitle\": \"Resultado do build\",\"activityImage\": \"https://ac-buckets-dev-acpublicmedia-2cxkd4j0deg1.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/GreenThumbUP.png\",\"facts\": [{\"name\": \"Message\",\"value\": \"Sucesso: Deploy em $DEPLOY_STAGE de $REPO\"}, {\"name\": \"Status\",\"value\": \"Success\"},{\"name\": \"Job\",\"value\": \"${JOB_NAME}:${BUILD_NUMBER}\"}],\"markdown\": true}],\"potentialAction\": [{\"@type\": \"OpenUri\",\"name\": \"Abrir Build\",\"targets\": [{ \"os\": \"default\", \"uri\": \"${BUILD_URL}\" }]}]}'")
      }
    }
```

Logs:

```
[Office365connector] Failed to post data to webhook - webhook
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <> != </*.clo.footprintdns.com/*.hotmail.com/*.internal.outlook.com/*.live.com/*.nrb.footprintdns.com/*.office.com/*.office365.com/*.outlook.com/*.outlook.office365.com/attachment.outlook.live.net/attachment.outlook.office.net/attachment.outlook.officeppe.net/attachments.office.net/attachments-sdf.office.net/ccs.login.microsoftonline.com/ccs-sdf.login.microsoftonline.com/hotmail.com/mail.services.live.com/office365.com/outlook.com/outlook.office.com/substrate.office.com/substrate-sdf.office.com/outlook.com>
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:339)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:275)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:258)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:167)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:714)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:394)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:178)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:330)
        at jenkins.plugins.office365connector.HttpWorker.run(HttpWorker.java:83)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Como posso resolver este problema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foi trocado o servidor do webhook https://compasso.webhook.office.com/ para https://outlook.office.com/webhook e funcionou

Answer (score -3):

Boa tarde Jackson
Tive o mesmo problema que o seu. Consegui resolvendo com a atualização do Java (na realidade, substituindo pelo OpenJDK).
Precisei atualizar os seguintes plugins no Jenkins:

- Office-365-Connector
- token-macro
- workflow-step-api

Tudo feito, as notificações voltaram à aparecer normalmente no canal do Teams.